# How to decrease flutter app size in android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bundle

I make my app using flutter and my app size is more than 100 mb and app has 15 screens.

It's android size is more than 100 mb and iOS app size is 40 mb I have to make it small
and I want proper solution for this

I try to compress my image files but it just decrease 8 mb

I want proper solution for compress flutter app size.

Comment: which command do you use to make apk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this below steps it may help you to reduce app size (only Android), i have reduced my 48mb build to 14mb

**Step 1:** android/gradle.properties
`android.enableR8=true`

**Step 2:** android/app/build.gradle

inside -> buildTypes -> release

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
useProguard true
```

**Step 3:**

Run

`flutter build apk --target-platform=android-arm`

or

`flutter build apk --split-per-abi`

**Some other optimizing tips,**

**1. Image assets**

Upload the images in permanent storage path like AWS or in your website server and use the link to that image in your code.

**2. Icons**

Its recommended to use from Material Icons or Cupertino Icons class. You can add --tree-shake-icons option to flutter build command, to remove all of the not used icons from the bundle. This will potentially save the size of your app. (use svg format icons)

**3. Fonts**

If we are using more fonts from local assets similar like images these fonts will also increase app size. The best solution is to use google_fonts plugin. This pluign will dynamically download font when it is used.

**4. Dynamic App Delivery**

We could build an app bundle if we are uploading to playstore or we could split the apk per abi which splits the apk to x64 and x86 bit code. By using appbundle Google Play’s new app serving model, called Dynamic Delivery, uses your app bundle to generate and serve optimized APKs for each user’s device configuration, so they download only the code and resources they need to run your app.

`Refer below links for more understanding,`

1. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code
2. https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9D63S4ZRBls

Comment: does it effect on performance of my app?

Comment: No, since it will increase your app performance. And checkout new Flutter SDK 2.8 which will boosts mobile performance. https://www.infoworld.com/article/3644228/flutter-28-boosts-mobile-performance.html

Comment: it work for me now I want to create it for publish there is any command for that

Comment: There is no command to do. Do all the steps above mentioned and create app bundle from android studio and publish it. Will work 100 percent.

Answer (score 0):

1. How many third-party packages are you using?
2. Did you use drag and drop to create the app or code everything manually?
3. Did you properly use `const` in objects that are repeated but are essentially the same? Like `const EdgeInsets.all(8.0)`.
4. Do you have a lot of gradient images that you can convert to Container gradients?

Comment: I am not using drag and drop feature I use only 10 images for app and 12 images for android res and I use const properly my code has only few yellow lines but still my app size is to large

Comment: If you are sure the bottleneck is the images, maybe only keep low res images on the phone and scale up, then use `Image.network` to load full res images from the net hosted on a CDN.

Comment: but image size is not more than 18 mbs

Answer (score 0):

1. Use webp images instead of PNG or JPEG
2. Add pro-guard files
3. Minify Enabled - true
4. Shrink- Resource -true

Comment: how much size is compress by using this

Comment: Pro guard eliminates all non used codes from the project files and also from library files.

Answer (score 0):

try running:

```
flutter clean
```

and then:

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

you could even further reduce the size of your code by doing:

```
flutter build apk --split-debug-info=/<project-name>/<directory>
```

and if you're willing to take the risk, you can [obfuscate](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/obfuscate) your code:

```
flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/<project-name>/<directory>
```

where

> /<'project-name'>/<'directory'>

is the directory where Flutter can output your app debug files.

Comment: is it safe because I have to send build to buy client

Comment: all commands listed are completely safe, except obfuscation.
obfuscation is only risky if your code relies on matching classes, functions, or libraries. 

i believe the first 2 - 3 commands will solve your problem. :)

Comment: what do you mean by "if code relies on matching classes" ?